# Ionic2 (Beta 10) Templates Build Directory under www

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am a JavaScript, Angular 1, and Ionic 1 dev.  I'm forcing myself to learn TypeScript, Angular 2, and Ionic 2.  With the Ionic2 (Beta 10) Templates, I don't understand what GENERATES the build directory under the www directory? Is that TypeScript that's generating the contents of that directory? Is it Angular2 somehow? Or Ionic 2? Is this build directory a common thing for something? Is this supposed to resemeble a "build" directory that gets created like traditional compiled languages do (Java, C#)?  Is the BUILD word common?  Can this be configured? What's a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic2 provides a gulpfile containing the build task. This task generates the build directory, which could be considered as best practise.

You can configure it in the gulpfile. However, the main work is done in the package [ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript). In its documentation, you can find how to configure the output directory for the typescript build, par example.